# Has switching hosting and backend any influence on Google Adwords?

Tags: google-ads

We created an almost identical copy of our web page which has been created in **WordPress**. Now, it runs on **Django/Python** so we have to change hosting to make it work.

But there is an **AdWords** campaign running on our web.

I'm curious, whether changing the backend and hosting could have any negative influence on **AdWords**? The domain remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

It ***might***.

There are many factors which help your rank, some of which can be affected by your hosting.

Speed is a mayor one. If the new host is slower/faster, there might be a change accordingly.
Shared hosting, a lot of domains on 1 IP address, will have a negative effect beause it might be less secure (one could be hacked and infect others on the shared server), so less juice from Google.

If you go from one decent host to another decent host: Barely any change.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword agnostic factors influence AdWords QS and CPC accordingly. If your new hosting is significantly slower it will decrease your Landing page experience, hence QS. This will raise the CPC.
Because AdWords send the user to the Final URL be careful that the URL's stay the same. You could use 301 redirects, but be very cautious with redirects!